# Kotlin Multiplatform error :shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosSimulatorArm64

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I setup a KMP project but I can't start the iOS Simulator. Android works perfectly. When trying to run the iOS the following gradle task fails:

```
The /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
ld: unknown options: -ios_simulator_version_min -sdk_version
```

I didn't do any changes to the project after creating it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're probably using Xcode 15 and an older version of Kotlin. If on Xcode 15, bump Kotlin to 1.9.10. Alternatively, install Xcode 14.3.1.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin. Spend a Whole Day on Finding The Solution.

Comment: Note that you're using Compose, you need to update the compiler plugin version to 1.5.3 so that it's compatible with Kotlin 1.9.10.