# Kotlin Multiplatform: Execution failed for task ':shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosSimulatorArm64'

Tags: ios, xcode, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

When trying to build a Kotlin Multiplatform App for iOS (from both Xcode and Android Studio), an error returns regarding the linkDebugFramework and the PhaseScriptExecution run script.

This stacktrace is output:

```
> Task :shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosSimulatorArm64 FAILED
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld invocation reported errors

The /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld command returned non-zero exit code: 1.
output:
ld: unknown options: -ios_simulator_version_min -sdk_version 
error: Compilation finished with errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':shared:linkDebugFrameworkIosSimulatorArm64'.
> Compilation finished with errors

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    PhaseScriptExecution Run\ Script /Users/[user]/Desktop/[app]/build/ios/[app-name].build/Debug-iphonesimulator/[app-name].build/Script-7555FFB5242A651A00829871.sh (in target '[app-name]' from project '[app-name]')
(1 failure)
```

So far, I have tried:

- Setting xcodebuild command line version
- clearing iOS build folder
- reinstalling xcode and android studio
- clearing gradle cache, rebuilding gradle

---

What worked for me was updating my build.gradle.kts to include:

```kotlin
id("com.android.application").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
    id("com.android.library").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin").version("2.0.1").apply(false)
    kotlin("android").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("plugin.serialization").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
```

Downgrading xcode did not work.

Comment: I solved by changing this code in build.gradle.kts

id("com.android.application").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
    id("com.android.library").version("8.1.0").apply(false)
    id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin").version("2.0.1") apply (false)
    kotlin("android").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version("1.9.10")

I changed 1.9.0 to 1.9.10
and also update android studio to 2022.3.1 Patch 1,  JDK Coretto 17.0.8

Comment: This worked for me, thank you !!

Comment: you really saved my life.. works like charm.. thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

You're probably using Xcode 15 and an older version of Kotlin. If on Xcode 15, bump Kotlin to 1.9.10. Alternatively, install Xcode 14.3.1.

Same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77150623/227313

:)

Comment: Both Xcode 15 and Xcode 14.3.1 have this issue for me. My Kotlin is on 1.9.0 but Android Studio says it is using the latest version available, is there an alternative way to install it? [https://imgur.com/a/ic1hFf7](https://imgur.com/a/ic1hFf7)

Comment: I solved by changing this code in build.gradle.kts 

id("com.android.application").version("8.1.0").apply(false) id("com.android.library").version("8.1.0").apply(false) id("com.google.android.libraries.mapsplatform.secrets-gradle-plugin").version("2.0.1") apply (false) kotlin("android").version("1.9.10").apply(false) kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.9.10").apply(false) kotlin("plugin.serialization") version("1.9.10") 

I changed 1.9.0 to 1.9.10 and also update android studio to 2022.3.1 Patch 1, JDK Coretto 17.0.8